# How to close the connection

Tags: python, http-headers, bottle

I'm migrating a simple toolset from python 2.7 to 3.5 and one of the tools is a simple web server using web.py.

Unfortunately web.py is not available for 3.5 yet so I switched to bottle.py for this.

According to the specification of the interface I'm creating I need to close the connection which I can do quite easily in web.py by adding the following line:

```
web.header('Connection', 'close')
```

But using bottle I get the error that hop-by-hop headers are not allowed when I do the following:

```
response.add_header('Connection', 'close')
```

How do I add this header to the response anyway? I've read the bottle documentation, searched online and looked through the bottle code.

Comment: Bottle is a WSGI framework and the [WSGI protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) explicitly forbids to set hop-by-hop headers: `Applications and middleware are forbidden from using HTTP/1.1 "hop-by-hop" features or headers`. Maybe you can convince the http server to set the header. But are you sure you need to set that manually, shouldn't the http server already deal with that? Or is that some custom http protocol you are dealing with?

Comment: That actually explains quite a lot. But I need to send the Connection: close in the header to the client for the basic reason that some Clients do not handle the response correctly otherwise.

Comment: Do you use the builtin bottle development server? You should probably only use that for, well, development.

Comment: It is just a tool for testing, it is run directly from the development environment so yes I do use the builtin server.

Comment: Then I think you have to use the approach I outlined. If you used something like nginx that should have been configurable (e.g. see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-send-custom-http-headers/) although I don't know if that also works for your special case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure so take what I write with a grain of salt.

The bottle development server is a lightly modified wsgiref server which is a sligthly modified http.server server. It has no easy methods or configurations to send "unusual" headers. You can though subclass it and write some custom code. I think it should be enough to overwrite the send_head method ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/server.py#L649)) and include `self.send_header("Connection", "close")` somewhere.

You can use bottly with any wsgi server you like. It has inbuild support for quite some servers, but any wsgi server should be able to serve the app. Maybe there is an easier way for other servers to send the custom header.

Also the http.server is not meant for production so you might want to change it even if you can get your header to work. If it is only for internal usage you might get away with using it.

Comment: This turns out to be the right answer, Bottle seems to actively prevent setting this since it is not part of the wsgi protocol, this should be set in the server itself, not in the application running on the server.