# How to get WSGI servers to close a connection after each response?

Tags: python, bottle, wsgiref

The API for Python's [wsgiref module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref) precludes [hop-by-hop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.util.is_hop_by_hop) headers (as defined in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html)).

I'm unclear on how to get the server to terminate a connection after a response (since there doesn't seem to be a way to add `Connection: close`).

This problem comes up in testing small WSGI apps and [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) micro-services.  Calls from [*curl*](https://curl.haxx.se/) get blocked by open connections from a browser.  I have to click a browser refresh to terminate the connection so that the pending curl request can be answers.

Obviously, this should be a server side decision (terminate connection after a response) rather than client-side.  I'm unclear how to implement this.

Comment: This may be helpful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079916/how-to-close-the-connection

Comment: Thanks @Ajax1234 . The other question is related but doesn't get to the heart of the matter which is "what is the correct way for an app to notify a WSGI server that it needs to terminate a session after fulfilling the response?"  The connection-close header is specifically disallowed, so there much be some other way to communicate, "here's your answer, now we're done, goodbye".

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do this. But couldn't you achieve your aim by using (for example) gevent to handle concurrent requests?

Answer (score 0):

This is really predicated on your WSGI server you are hosting your framework via.  The best solution with bottle is to run it through gevent.

```
botapp = bottle.app()
for Route in (mainappRoute,): #handle multiple files containing routes
    botapp.merge(Route)
botapp = SessionMiddleware(botapp, beakerconfig) #in case you are using beaker sessions
botapp = WhiteNoise(botapp) #in case you want whitenoise to handle static files
botapp.add_files(staticfolder, prefix='static/') #add static route to whitenoise
server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", int(80)), botapp) #gevent async web server
def shutdown():
    print('Shutting down ...')
    server.stop(timeout=60)
    exit(signal.SIGTERM)
gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown) #CTRL C
server.serve_forever() #spawn the server
```

You can purge the whitenoise and bottle configs if they aren't necessary, I kept them there as an example, and a suggestion that you use them if this is outward facing.

This is purely asynchronous on every connection.